# Graph proportion by category in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph the proportion of people in Remission (which is binary 0/1) after treatment by year. I can find how to graph the count, but I would like the proportion as there are a different number of people each year.

My data look something like this:

| Client_id | Year | Remission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2016 | 0 |
| 4 | 2017 | 1 |
| 7 | 2017 | 0 |
| 8 | 2016 | 1 |
| 12 | 2016 | 1 |

I would like to create a plot with Year on the x-axis and the proportion of those in remission on the y-axis. Ideally, I would be able to do this both using geom_bar and geom_line.

I have tried this code, but it gives a proportion of 1.00 for every year, which is not correct.

```
ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year,y=Remission),stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

I could calculate this manually for each year and create a table using Excel, but hoping for a way to complete it in ggplot2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position = "fill"` in your `geom_bar` and use `fill = Remission` in your `ggplot` aesthetics like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.character(Year),
         Remission = as.factor(Remission)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, fill = Remission)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  labs(y = "Proportion")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Percentage scale**

If you want a percentage scale, you can use the package `scales` with function `percent_format()` in `scale_y_continuous` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.character(Year),
         Remission = as.factor(Remission)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, fill = Remission)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) +
  labs(y = "Proportion")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Proportion with geom_line**

You can do this by first calculating the proportion using `count` and `group_by` with a `mutate` and plot the data like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year),
         Remission = as.factor(Remission)) %>%
  count(Year, Remission) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y = prop, color = Remission)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2016,2017)) +
  labs(y = "Proportion")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: that worked well, thanks! How can I do the same thing with geom_line? Ideally, I want to combine multiple measures of Remission and need to do a line graph for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Steven, I added some code for that!

Comment: is there a way to suppress the "0" line so that it only gives the proportion of those in Remission?

Comment: @Steven, you could filter your data by using `filter(Remission == 1)`.