# Adding data labels to geom_bar when using proportions

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I had previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445955/graph-proportion-by-category-in-ggplot2/73446058?noredirect=1#comment129704846_73446058) about using geom_bar to plot the proportions of a binary variable.

This solution worked well. Now I need to add data labels to the plot. However, geom_text requires a y and label, and I am not sure how to do that using the following syntax

```
df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.character(Year),
         Remission = as.factor(Remission)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, fill = Remission)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  labs(y = "Proportion")
```

Is it possible to add data labels to this kind of stacked bar chart?

Secondary question: given that it is a proportion, the top and bottom labels provide the same information. Is it possible to only label the "lower" bar?

Comment: I linked to the FAQ on the topic: if you still have trouble I'd suggest asking a new question that includes sample data to illustrate the problem and shows your attempt(s) based on the FAQ--understanding the problem and what's been tried will make it easy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although ggplot is good at performing common summary operations, people sometimes tie themselves in knots trying to get ggplot to do data wrangling that is actually straightforward to do *en route* to ggplot. Simply create the proportions and labels as columns in the data you are passing.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.character(Year),
         Remission = as.factor(Remission)) %>%
  group_by(Year, Remission) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(Proportion = n/sum(n), 
         label = ifelse(Remission == 1, scales::percent(Proportion), "")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Proportion, fill = Remission)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), aes(label = label),
            size = 7) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  labs(y = "Proportion") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

---

**Data from previous question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Client_id = c(2L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 12L), Year = c(2016L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2016L, 2016L), Remission = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```